# Use Angular4 functions like (click) [src] inside [innerHTML] of Angular4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, dom, sanitization

I'm using markdown-it compiler to convert markdown text in html which I'm displaying using innerHTML.but problem is that I want to add function to some particular div and use [src] to display sanitized url of youtube in iframe.

it showing me error that sanitizer has stripped some part of code and no javascript functionality is working inside [innerHTML].

I heard that $compiler was the solution in angularJS. is it still  available for ANgular4 and yes than can anyone help me to implement it?

Can any one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you read [compiler doc](https://angular.io/api/core/Compiler) ?

Comment: It doesn't contain information i REQUIRE.

Comment: @YASHDAVE can you add the sample code what are you trying to do. Means how are you trying to pass url through src..

Comment: Please add your code. That will be more helpful.

Comment: It will not allow you to add any js code inside innerHTML. You have to bind the event later.